# How come my ContextInitializer for EF 6 has zero refrences?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, code-first

I'm trying to learn EF 6 Code-first in WPF by following some tutorials. Since I'm familiar with model-first I can understand most parts except I've found `ContextInitializer` a little confusing. I defined a `ContextInitializer` like this code:

```
public class ContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Context>
{
    protected override void Seed(Context context)
    {
        var customers = new List<Customer>
        {
        new Customer{Name="Jane",Phone="2238718"},
        new Customer{Name="David",Phone="43245608"},
        new Customer{Name="Mike",Phone="90814417"}
        };
        customers.ForEach(cu => context.Customers.Add(cu));
        context.SaveChanges();

    }
}
```

and this is my `Context` class:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context()
        : base("MVVM")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

}
```

and It created a database at first run which I think it's weird because this class has **zero refrences**. Since `Seed` method doesn't fire again, I can't understand how this works.

Can someone explain to me how my ContextInitializer with zero reference created a database?

Comment: Your database should not be created until the Context is queried (on first run). Sure its not the old database left over?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure because I just wrote a simple application for learning code-first and there was no older database.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *zero references*? Note that a code-first context always creates a database, even if you don't configure an initializer explicitly.

Comment: I mean `ContextInitializer` class it never instantiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following section exist in your `App.Config`?

```
<contexts>
  <context type="(your name space).Context, MVVM">
    <databaseInitializer type="(your name space).ContextInitializer, MVVM" />
  </context>
</contexts>
```

If it is, the program knows where to look to find the `ContextInitializer`. If the database already exists and the tables in the database already match those of the POCO/model classes, nothing happens. If the model has changed or the database doesn’t exist, this class will be invoked, resulting in the database being seeded with your data.